# Spring Boot YAML profiles configuration file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to test YAML profiles with Spring Boot. The following `yaml-props.yml` is my configuration file:

```
name: def
---
spring:
   profiles: live
   name: live
---
spring:
   profiles: test
   name: test
```

Also, I've set the `spring.profiles.active` property to `live` inside `application.properties` file
(both configuration files are under `src/test/resources` folder.)
Finally, here is my test class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:yaml-props.yml")
public class YMLUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private YMLProps ymlProps;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void testYmlProps() {

        assertEquals("live", env.getActiveProfiles()[0]); // Active profile is 'live'
        assertEquals("live", ymlProps.getName()); // Fails here!
    }
}
```

However, the test fails in the second assertion:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <live> but was: <test>
```

It seems that Spring picks the last defined profile. Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml` file and `YMLProps` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following after `@SpringBootTest`.

```
@SpringBootTest(value={"spring.profiles.active=live"})
```

I hope it works !

Comment: Can you try splitting uncommon properties to two different files according to profiles e.g. `application-test.yml` or `application-live.yml` and then I think this property would work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your configuration file is wrong (notice indentation), it should be:

```
name: def
---
spring:
  profiles: live
name: live
---
spring:
  profiles: test
name: test
```

Second problem is, that **you cannot** use YAML files everywhere, where you can use property files and `@TestPropertySource` is such case, where you cannot simply use YAML file...

If you use `application.yml` it's easy, but might be confusing. If you want to use multiple YAML files I'd recommend you to use `-Dspring.config.additional-location=classpath:yaml-props.yml`.

Here is my **pom.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>springTests-springBootTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**YMLProps class**

```java
package betlista.springTests.springBootTest;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class YMLProps {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**YMLUnitTest class**

```java
package betlista.springTests.springBootTest;

import betlista.springTests.springBootTest.YMLProps;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test,live")
public class YMLUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private YMLProps ymlProps;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void testYmlProps() {
        String[] activeProfiles = env.getActiveProfiles();
        Assert.assertEquals("live", activeProfiles[1]); // Active profile is 'live'
        Assert.assertEquals("live", ymlProps.getName()); // Fails here!
    }

}
```

All available on GitHub: https://github.com/Betlista/SpringTests/tree/master/YMLProps